# Unable to add a form in a site page

Tags: community, force.com-sites, site.com

[image]I have create a site page, i an trying to add a form in that page but when I select Add Page Elements option I cannot find Form section.  I am using Salesforce Developer edition, I gave read & write permissions to various objects and the role is Site Administrator.

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Sriram Lns. It would be very helpful to anyone who tries to respond to your post if you included your code. Please take the time to visit [Help] and take our [Tour] to better understand how this forum works, including [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). We want your experience here to be a positive one where you'll be able to receive the answers you need and contribute to the community if you choose to. Thank you.

Comment: Having the same problem, I didn't have this problem 2 days ago. I had an issue logged w/ SF on another issue, that got fixed, but then this happened. I don't see most of the page elements I'm used to , I see their page elements for their delivered stuff: login, profiles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using site.com studio then you can add form on page as shown in snapshot below:

[image]

Comment: Form section is not displayed at all when I check the Page Elements tab.  Please check above image and let me know if I need to change any settings so that Form section appears, also DATA section is not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Was only able to access forms and data elements when I DID NOT use an existing template. Conclusion I came to: Templates say they have "known limitations" so I suppose this is one. Good Luck!

Comment: I have created a new template and included it in a new page still I cannot see FORM and DATA ELEMENT section in the page.  I made the template editable but it didnt work.  Can you please guide me through this issue.  I am using Developer instance.

Comment: I am using an enterprise edition and I think the dev instance has limitations --might be worth looking into those limitations before proceeding.

Comment: I had to remove any of the pre-built templates from my page to access forms/data again. To the extent where forms/data would disappear again if I started with my own blank template, then added a prebuilt template.